# Sample of Runners - Can the Group Run 2.5 Miles in 20 mins?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, t-test, standard-deviation, outliers

I have a dataset where there are 6 runners. Each runner runs as far as they can for 20 mins, and a watcher records their distance (to the nearest 0.1 miles) at certain times, precisely on the minute mark. For example, a runner may run 0.4 mi at 2 mins, then 0.8 mi in 6 mins, etc. The time intervals are not the same for everyone - one runner could have been recorded at 2, 4, 6,..., another may be at 2, 5, 8,...

I'm interested in knowing if this group, as a whole, should join a running division where teams run a 20 min race to a specified distance.

Could someone give me a best method to check this data? My plan is to:

1. I'd like to remove outliers - is there a best method to do this?
2. Categorize everything by the time intervals the watchers recorded. From there, do a t-test for a 95% confidence interval and only look at the data that falls into that range. Repeat this step for each time interval. I may ignore time intervals that only have 1 data point?
3. Once Step 2 is complete, I'll only plot the data that fits in the CI. From there, I'll do a linear trend to estimate where the data overall goes. From the trend line, I should be able to figure out how far this group, as a whole, will run in 20 mins with 95% confidence.

Am I on the right track? Does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I do not understand step #2. What is the purpose of filtering based on the confidence interval? Outlier removal? // What is the purpose of the regression in step #3?

Comment: The point of filtering on the CI is to get the "good" data and remove the "bad", so yes, I guess outlier removal. My final plot will still have a few data points at each time of sampling, so the regression is just to see a projection. With the linear curve, I'm hoping to see where the data points line up (e.g., the linear curve could show 2.3 miles at 20 mins, so the runners would be short of the 2.5 mile goal).

Comment: Could you explain what it means for a *group* to run a race?  Would it be the number of members reaching a target distance within 20 minutes? The shortest distance run by anyone?  The longest?  Or would it perhaps be a relay optimized to achieve the longest distance during 20 minutes? Or maybe the total distance run by all group members in 20 minutes?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: My data has 6 runners in it, so a "group" would mean that all 6 of these runners can go into a race to run a set distance and have a good chance of making it. For instance, if 5/6 runners are making it 2 mi in 20 mins, I may want to put them in that race and not a 3 mi in 20 mins race. I'm looking for a way to use statistics to justify an answer.

Comment: kjetil, this is not a textbook/homework question. I've got some data that I'm looking at and I'm using a runner analogy to simplify it. What I've tried are listed in the steps from the description of the problem.